# how to get the correct image path on amazons3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm using the following code to get the path of images on S3

```
Storage::getDriver()
                ->getAdapter()
                ->getClient()
                ->getObjectUrl(env('S3_BUCKET_NAME'), $key);
```

this url returns BUCKETNAME.s3-eu-west-1-amazon.com/$key

while the real url of the image is s3-eu-west-1-amazon.com/BUCKETNAME/$key

what to do get the same url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 supports 2 types of object URLs:

- path style: **$host/$bucket/$key**
- virtual host style: **$bucket.$host/$key**

You can find more information about them here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro

The URL you're getting from the client should work regardless of the format. The format used depends on:

- format of the endpoint client is using - IPs result in path style URLs
- bucket name - some bucket names are not valid DNS names and will result in path-style as well